# Reordering input using same pattern until it change back to the original order

Tags: arrays, algorithm, permutation, shuffle

I found this interview question and wonder if there's any good way to solve it. We have an input array [0, 1, 2, 3] and a pattern array, e.g. [3,1,2,0], what the pattern array does is that we should reorder the input by putting the element at the index of 3 to the first position, then put the element at the index of 1 to the second position etc. So after one iteration, [0, 1, 2, 3] will become [3, 1, 2, 0], after another iteration of reordering using the same pattern, it becomes [0, 1, 2, 3] again.

The question is how many times do we need to iterate given a pattern so it go back to the original order, and is it possible that the input array can never go back to original order given certain reordering pattern?

---

That's the question, I myself only know how to brute force to solve it - keep iterating it until it's the same order as the original input. About whether it may never go back to the original order, my approach is to record all the orderings we've seen so far, and when we found an ordering that's already been visited, we realize there's a loop and we may never get back to the original. 
My analysis in this paragraph is probably useless, so feel free to ignore it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a notation of permutations, called cyclic notation, which will help you in this case. The cyclic notation for the example pattern is:

```
(0 3) (1 2)
```

It means: The entry at position `0` goes to position `3`. Entry at position `3` goes to position `0` (just wrap around). Entry at position `1` goes to `2` and `2` goes to `1`. It's also possible to get larger cycles, e.g.:

```
(0 3 1) (2)
```

For this permutation, the result would look as follows:

```
      a b c d
It 1: b d c a
It 2: d a c b
It 3: a b c d
```

So this case requires three iterations to get back to its original order. This number can be derived directly from the cyclic notation. In the first example, there are two cycles with two entries each. The number of total cycles required is the least common multiple `lcm(2, 2) = 2`. In the second example, it is `lcm(3, 1) = 3`.

And deriving the cyclic notation is not too hard. You just need to iterate the pattern. If you encounter an entry that is not yet part of a cycle, follow its path through the pattern and remember the cycle's length. This will give you the lengths of all included cycles. Finally, calculate the LCM and report that as the result.

Comment: Thanks...I feel it's quite hard to realize this pattern during an interview without knowing or reading about it before hand.